# porque iframe extraido de csv se interpreta como ASCII

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente código en el controlador, lo que hace es recibir un id desde la url y genero un array en el que viene el `iframe` estoy utilizando PHP 7.5 con framework codeigniter 4.

```
 public function getVideoEmbedCode(string $originalId = null)
{
    $getVideo = $this->getResults('video_embed_code', [
        'id' => $originalId
    ]);

    $array = json_decode(json_encode($getVideo), true);

    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $d['frameVideo'] = $value["code"]; 
    }

    $data["embedVideo"] = $d;

    echo view('header');
    echo view('viewVideo', $data);
    echo view('footer');
}
```

Luego lo imprimo en la vista de la siguiente manera:

```
<section id="view_video">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php foreach ($embedVideo as $key => $video) : ?>
                    <?php echo $video; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Aquí es donde esta el problema al interpretar el código HTML lo hace como una cadena de texto y al ver el código fuente de la pagina veo que esta escribiendo lo siguiente:

```
&lt;iframe src=&quot;https://www.dominio.com/embed/6736h&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;340&quot; scrolling=&quot;no&quot; allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso no es código ASCII, sino entidades HTML. Solo necesitas [decodificar](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.html-entity-decode.php) para que se muestre correctamente:

```
<section id="view_video">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php
                foreach ($embedVideo as $key => $video) :
                    echo html_entity_decode($video);
                endforeach;
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Resultado:

```
<iframe src="https://www.dominio.com/embed/6736h" frameborder="0" width="560" height="340" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Por cierto, no necesitas abrir `<?php` y cerrar `?>` las etiquetas PHP en cada línea, solo hace el código ilegible.

Comment: Gracias, funciono perfectamente.